# How to evenly space columns across window width when there is sufficient space available?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am using Bootstrap's ***col-lg-12*** on a div. It shows the columns nicely when there are available columns(/data). PSB:
[image]

But when there is not enough info available the right side space remains blank. PSB:
[image]

In this kind of scenario is it possible to dynamically expand the width of the available columns/divs to occupy the whole window?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Yes code would be helpful but if i understand your question correctly ... you are also using col-lg-2 to display your tiles. So you will need to apply a dynamic Bootstrap class of col-lg-## where ## 12/(number of tiles). ie your tiles in your second picture would be col-lg-4 as 4x3 = 12. Also you will need to decided what to do when you have a number of tiles that does not divide into 12 (5 or 7 - 11 for instance).

Comment: You don't _have_ to use bootstrap grid if you're already using bootstrap. This can be easily done using flexbox with `justify-content: space-around;`.

Comment: Hi @fjoe, got your point.
Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Masonry would work well here if you're open to using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly ... you are also using col-lg-2 to display your tiles. So you will need to apply a dynamic Bootstrap class of col-lg-## where ## is 12/(number of tiles).

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-##"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-##"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-##"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where in you second picture ## would be col-lg-4 as 4x3 = 12.

Also you will need to decided what to do when you have a number of tiles that does not divide into 12 (5 or 7 - 11 for instance)

As people have commented there are other options and frameworks that you can use to solve this problem fully but this answers your questions directly and with Bootstrap.